# If $X_1, X_2, \dots$ are independent then $P(\limsup X_n = a) = P(\liminf X_n = b) = 1 $ for some $a,b\in \mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty, \infty\}$

Tags: probability-theory

How can we prove that if $X_1, X_2, \dots$ are independent random variables and
$$
Y = \limsup_{n \to \infty} X_n, Z = \liminf_{n \to \infty} X_n
$$
then $P(Y = a) = P(Z = b) = 1$ for some $a,b\in \mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty, \infty\}$.

Is this the same as Kolmogorov's $0-1$ law?

Comment: Please check my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Y$ is measurable w.r.t. $\bigcap_{m=1}^\infty \sigma(X_m, X_{m+1},\dots)$. Hence, by Kolmogorov's $0-1$ law we have $\mathbb{P}(Y\in A)\in \{0,1\}$ for all Borel sets $A$. Such a variable must be almost surely constant (exercise!).

Similarly, you do the same for $Z$.

Answer (score 1):

$\limsup X_n$ and $\lim\inf X_n$ are measurble w.r.t. the tail sigma field. Any function measurable w.r.t. the tail sigma filed is  almost surely constant since every event in the tail sigma field has probability $0$ or $1$. Take $a$ and $b$ to be these constant values.

Comment: And how do we know that every event in the tail sigma field has probability
0 or 1?

Comment: @math_beginner See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_zero%E2%80%93one_law